# React-dnd drop failure state

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I'm using the [react-dnd](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd) library to manage drag/drop, and running into what feels like a limitation, but wanting to make sure I'm not just overlooking something.

I've got a React component implementing `useDrop` with a fairly complicated set of rules inside `canDrop`. When the user releases the mouse and `canDrop` returns false, I'd love to be able to provide a detailed error message so they know *why* they weren't allowed to drop the item, but `drop` isn't called (expected behavior, per [the docs](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/use-drop#specification-object-members)), and there doesn't appear to be any way to provide context back to the `useDrag` handler's `end` function either.

I could obviously fire the error message from `canDrop` itself, but that function is called hundreds of times for each drag, so that introduces issues like debouncing etc. that I'd prefer to avoid.

So my question is, have I just run into a limitation of the library, or am I missing an event/hook somewhere?

Comment: could please provide sample sandbox?

Comment: Sure — https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-feather-k9bt8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: In that sandbox, my goal would be to fire some sort of user facing error on either Dustbin's `drop` or Box's `end` (or really anywhere, for that matter) that explains that the drag failed because of `condition2`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and here is my solution:

1. `canDrop` contains the complex logic to determine if the item...can drop.
2. Add the item id (`itemId`) to the `collect` function passed to useDrop and use that id to determine what error message to show based on the combination of `!canDrop && itemId==='some specific id'`.

My useDrop hook:

```
  const [{ isOver, canDrop, itemId }, drop] = useDrop(
    () => ({
      accept: [{valid ids go here}],
      drop: (item, monitor) => {
        // omitted
      },
      canDrop: (item, monitor) => {
        // canDrop logic
      },
      collect: (monitor) => ({
        isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
        canDrop: !!monitor.canDrop(),
        itemId: monitor.getItem()?.id,
      }),
    }),
    []
  );
```

Then in your component render:

```
return (
  <>
    {canDrop && <span>You're good to drop</span>}
    {!canDrop && itemId === 'some condition' && <span>Error message specific to this condition</span>}
    {!canDrop && itemId === 'some other condition' && <span>Error message specific to this condition</span>}
  </>
)
```

For my scenario the item's id lets me determine the error message I should show but I think you could also return the entire item from the `collect` function.